# Spring MVC - How to make a unique bean for each user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm creating a Spring MVC application, and this application should work
like a shop, where each user has its own basket of products. The purchase are made in two steps :

- Form with product and its amount.
- Form with buyer adress,name,email and so on.

The problem is : when one site visitor is on the second step(second form) the basket of the another site visitor has the same product list.Basket is a bean with different product containers and the product range is strictly limited,so I created bean with amount for each product.
Basket.class:

```
public class Basket {

    private CPContainer cpContainer;

    private FBContainer fbContainer;

    private JumperContainer jumperContainer;

    private VBContainer vbContainer;

    private BBContainer bbContainer;

    private PBContainer pbContainer;

    private List<Product>order = new ArrayList<>();

    private int mass;

    private static final int maxMass = 100000;

    public int calculateMass() {
        mass = 0;
        order.clear();

        mass+=massOfContainer(fbContainer);
        mass+=massOfContainer(cpContainer);
        mass+=massOfContainer(jumperContainer);
        mass+=massOfContainer(vbContainer);
        mass+=massOfContainer(bbContainer);
        mass+=massOfContainer(pbContainer);

        return mass;
    }

    public int progressBarMass(){
        int progress = (mass * 100)/maxMass;
        return progress;
    }

    public int calculateFluid(){
        int V;
        V = ((progressBarMass()+5)/10)*10;
        return V;
    }

    private int massOfContainer(Container container) {
        int mass = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < container.getProducts().size(); i++) {
            Product product = container.getProductById(i);
            if (product.getAmount() > 0) {
                mass+=(product.getMass()*product.getAmount());
                order.add(product);//Добавляем продукт в заказ

                System.out.println(product + " amount: " +product.getAmount());
            }
        }
        return mass;
    }


    public CPContainer getCpContainer() {
        return cpContainer;
    }

    public void setCpContainer(CPContainer cpContainer) {
        this.cpContainer = cpContainer;
    }

    public FBContainer getFbContainer() {
        return fbContainer;
    }

    public void setFbContainer(FBContainer fbContainer) {
        this.fbContainer = fbContainer;
    }

    public JumperContainer getJumperContainer() {
        return jumperContainer;
    }

    public void setJumperContainer(JumperContainer jumperContainer) {
        this.jumperContainer = jumperContainer;
    }

    public VBContainer getVbContainer() {
        return vbContainer;
    }

    public void setVbContainer(VBContainer vbContainer) {
        this.vbContainer = vbContainer;
    }

    public BBContainer getBbContainer() {
        return bbContainer;
    }

    public void setBbContainer(BBContainer bbContainer) {
        this.bbContainer = bbContainer;
    }

    public PBContainer getPbContainer() {
        return pbContainer;
    }

    public void setPbContainer(PBContainer pbContainer) {
        this.pbContainer = pbContainer;
    }

    public List<Product> getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(List<Product> order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public int getMass() {
        return mass;
    }

    public void setMass(int mass) {
        this.mass = mass;
    }
}
```

For example CPProduct:

```
public class CPProduct implements Product{

    private int id;
    private int L;
    private int H;
    private int B;
    private int mass;
    private int amount;

    public int getL() {
        return L;
    }

    public void setL(int l) {
        L = l;
    }

    public int getH() {
        return H;
    }

    public void setH(int h) {
        H = h;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return B;
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        B = b;
    }

    public int getMass() {
        return mass;
    }

    public void setMass(int mass) {
        this.mass = mass;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "ПП " +
                (L) + "." + (H) + "." + (B) + " ";
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="WEB-INF/resources/"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.concrete"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="mainFlowRegistry"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="mainFlowExecutor"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="587"/>
        <property name="username" value="conbcrete@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="password" value="WetConcrete3puck33"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.ssl.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.from.email">conbcrete@gmail.com</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="mySender" class="com.concrete.services.EmailSender">
        <property name="receiver" value="budbum9@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="subject" value="Покупка бетонных изделий"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <util:list scope="prototype" id="FBList" value-type="com.concrete.pojo.product.FBProduct">
        <bean scope="prototype" id="fb1" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.FBProduct">
            <property name="id" value="0"/>
            <property name="mass" value="1000"/>
            <property name="l" value="8980"/>
            <property name="b" value="1490"/>
            <property name="h" value="220"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="fb2" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.FBProduct">
            <property name="id" value="1"/>
            <property name="mass" value="2000"/>
            <property name="l" value="8980"/>
            <property name="b" value="1190"/>
            <property name="h" value="220"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="fb3" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.FBProduct">
            <property name="id" value="2"/>
            <property name="mass" value="3000"/>
            <property name="l" value="7180"/>
            <property name="b" value="1490"/>
            <property name="h" value="220"/>
        </bean>
    </util:list>
    <util:list scope="prototype" id="CPList" value-type="com.concrete.pojo.product.CPProduct">
        <bean scope="prototype" id="fb1" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.CPProduct">
            <property name="id" value="0"/>
            <property name="mass" value="500"/>
            <property name="l" value="8980"/>
            <property name="b" value="1490"/>
            <property name="h" value="220"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="fb2" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.CPProduct">
            <property name="id" value="1"/>
            <property name="mass" value="1000"/>
            <property name="l" value="8980"/>
            <property name="b" value="1190"/>
            <property name="h" value="220"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="fb3" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.CPProduct">
            <property name="id" value="2"/>
            <property name="mass" value="1500"/>
            <property name="l" value="6180"/>
            <property name="b" value="1490"/>
            <property name="h" value="220"/>
        </bean>
    </util:list>
    <util:list scope="prototype" id="JumperList" value-type="com.concrete.pojo.product.JumperProduct">
        <bean scope="prototype" id="j1" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.JumperProduct">
            <property name="load" value="100"/>
            <property name="L" value="1030"/>
            <property name="B" value="120"/>
            <property name="H" value="65"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B15"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.008"/>
            <property name="mass" value="20"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="j2" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.JumperProduct">
            <property name="load" value="150"/>
            <property name="L" value="1290"/>
            <property name="B" value="120"/>
            <property name="H" value="65"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B15"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.010"/>
            <property name="mass" value="25"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="j3" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.JumperProduct">
            <property name="load" value="150"/>
            <property name="L" value="1550"/>
            <property name="B" value="120"/>
            <property name="H" value="65"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B15"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.012"/>
            <property name="mass" value="30"/>
        </bean>
    </util:list>
    <util:list scope="prototype" id="VBList" value-type="com.concrete.pojo.product.VBProduct">
        <bean scope="prototype" id="vb1" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.VBProduct">
            <property name="L" value="630"/>
            <property name="B" value="300"/>
            <property name="H" value="3280"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B15"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.62"/>
            <property name="mass" value="750"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="vb2" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.VBProduct">
            <property name="L" value="630"/>
            <property name="B" value="300"/>
            <property name="H" value="2980"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B15"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.56"/>
            <property name="mass" value="650"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="vb3" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.VBProduct">
            <property name="L" value="630"/>
            <property name="B" value="300"/>
            <property name="H" value="2780"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B15"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.53"/>
            <property name="mass" value="625"/>
        </bean>
    </util:list>
    <util:list scope="prototype" id="BBList" value-type="com.concrete.pojo.product.BBProduct">
        <bean scope="prototype" id="bb1" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.BBProduct">
            <property name="L" value="800"/>
            <property name="B" value="80"/>
            <property name="H" value="200"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B30"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.0128"/>
            <property name="mass" value="31"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="bb2" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.BBProduct">
            <property name="L" value="1000"/>
            <property name="B" value="80"/>
            <property name="H" value="200"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B30"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.016"/>
            <property name="mass" value="40"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="bb3" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.BBProduct">
            <property name="L" value="1000"/>
            <property name="B" value="180"/>
            <property name="H" value="300"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B30"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.052"/>
            <property name="mass" value="130"/>
        </bean>
    </util:list>
    <util:list scope="prototype" id="PBList" value-type="com.concrete.pojo.product.PBProduct">
        <bean scope="prototype" id="pb1" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.PBProduct">
            <property name="L" value="4000"/>
            <property name="B" value="300"/>
            <property name="H" value="300"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B25"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.37"/>
            <property name="mass" value="925"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="pb2" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.PBProduct">
            <property name="L" value="6000"/>
            <property name="B" value="300"/>
            <property name="H" value="300"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B25"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.55"/>
            <property name="mass" value="1375"/>
        </bean>
        <bean scope="prototype" id="pb3" class="com.concrete.pojo.product.PBProduct">
            <property name="L" value="8000"/>
            <property name="B" value="300"/>
            <property name="H" value="300"/>
            <property name="BClass" value="B25"/>
            <property name="V" value="0.74"/>
            <property name="mass" value="1825"/>
        </bean>
    </util:list>

    <bean scope="prototype" id="FBContainer" class="com.concrete.pojo.container.FBContainer">
        <property name="products" ref="FBList"/>
    </bean>

    <bean scope="prototype" id="CPContainer" class="com.concrete.pojo.container.CPContainer">
        <property name="products" ref="CPList"/>
    </bean>

    <bean scope="prototype" id="JumperContainer" class="com.concrete.pojo.container.JumperContainer">
        <property name="products" ref="JumperList"/>
    </bean>

    <bean scope="prototype" id="VBContainer" class="com.concrete.pojo.container.VBContainer">
        <property name="products" ref="VBList"/>
    </bean>

    <bean scope="prototype" id="BBContainer" class="com.concrete.pojo.container.BBContainer">
        <property name="products" ref="BBList"/>
    </bean>

    <bean scope="prototype" id="PBContainer" class="com.concrete.pojo.container.PBContainer">
        <property name="products" ref="PBList"/>
    </bean>

    <bean scope="prototype" id="basket" class="com.concrete.pojo.container.Basket">
        <property name="fbContainer" ref="FBContainer"/>
        <property name="cpContainer" ref="CPContainer"/>
        <property name="jumperContainer" ref="JumperContainer"/>
        <property name="vbContainer" ref="VBContainer"/>
        <property name="bbContainer" ref="BBContainer"/>
        <property name="pbContainer" ref="PBContainer"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

How do I make different baskets for different visitors?

Comment: Did you try using session scope?

Comment: @mathur Yes, I used session scope on every bean and list that now has scope="prototype".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was not in products or container - my @Controller had scope="singleton" so each visitor used the same controller. I changed controller scope to session and it works fine.